# PHP function with unknown number (Regexp type) $childIds[] = X,$child->id

Tags: php, foreach

Here is the structure of my categories in the database

```
Parent category A (category_id = 1)
Child category B (category_id = 2)
Child category C (category_id = 3)
Child category D (category_id = 4)
Child category E (category_id = 5)
```

Basically my Joomla extension does not allow you to classify a Page in several categories at the same time.
But I managed to get around this by modifying some php files, and adding several category_id values (separated by commas)

My code that works. But it's just too long. I would like to simplify it.
I had to create all the scenarios, depending on the position of the numbers.

My code :

```
// Get all child ids from this category
$categoryModel = ES::model('ClusterCategory');
$childs = $categoryModel->getChildCategories($activeCategory->id, [], SOCIAL_TYPE_PAGE, array('state' => SOCIAL_STATE_PUBLISHED));

$childIds = [];

foreach ($childs as $child) {
    $childIds[] = "1,$child->id";
    $childIds[] = "2,$child->id";
    $childIds[] = "3,$child->id";
    $childIds[] = "4,$child->id";
    $childIds[] = "5,$child->id";
    $childIds[] = "$child->id,1";
    $childIds[] = "$child->id,2";
    $childIds[] = "$child->id,3";
    $childIds[] = "$child->id,4";
    $childIds[] = "$child->id,5";   
    $childIds[] = "1,$child->id,2";
    $childIds[] = "2,$child->id,3";
    $childIds[] = "3,$child->id,4";
    $childIds[] = "4,$child->id,5";
    $childIds[] = "5,$child->id,1";
    $childIds[] = "2,$child->id,1";
    $childIds[] = "3,$child->id,2";
    $childIds[] = "4,$child->id,3";
    $childIds[] = "5,$child->id,4";
    $childIds[] = "1,$child->id,5";
    $childIds[] = $child->id;
}
```

My question :
**How to insert a variable instead of the number?**
I tried Regexp, and many other things.

As in an equation with an unknown.
$childIds[] = **X**,$child->id,**X**;

Comment: _adding several category_id values (separated by commas)_ This, if I understand what you mean here, may well be a very bad idea! [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: And what would be the solution to add a Regex in my case ?
$childIds[] = X,$child->id,X;

Comment: If you are a Joomla, you might ask your Joomla questions on [Joomla.se] Stack Exchange to help you with what really feels like an XY Problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use nested loops do do this.

```
$categoryModel = ES::model('ClusterCategory');
$childs = $categoryModel->getChildCategories($activeCategory->id, [], SOCIAL_TYPE_PAGE, array('state' => SOCIAL_STATE_PUBLISHED));
$childIds = [];

foreach ($childs as $child) {
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
        $childIds[] = "$i,$child->id";
        $childIds[] = "$child->id,$i";
        
        for ($j = 1; $j <= 5; $j++) {
            if ($i != $j) {
                $childIds[] = "$i,$child->id,$j";
                $childIds[] = "$i,$j,$child->id";
                
                for ($k = 1; $k <= 5; $k++) {
                    if ($i != $k && $j != $k) {
                        $childIds[] = "$i,$child->id,$j,$k";
                        $childIds[] = "$i,$j,$child->id,$k";
                        // Add more combinations as needed
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This way, you can easily adjust the range of numbers by changing the loop boundaries, and the code will be more maintainable.

But since nested loops in general are a very bad idea you should consider using a recursive function instead.

```
function generateCombinations($depth, $maxDepth, $currentCombination, $excludeValues, $childId, &$childIds) {
    if ($depth == $maxDepth) {
        $childIds[] = implode(',', $currentCombination);
        return;
    }

    for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
        if (!in_array($i, $excludeValues)) {
            $currentCombination[] = $i;
            generateCombinations($depth + 1, $maxDepth, $currentCombination, $excludeValues, $childId, $childIds);
            array_pop($currentCombination);
        }
    }
}

$categoryModel = ES::model('ClusterCategory');
$childs = $categoryModel->getChildCategories($activeCategory->id, [], SOCIAL_TYPE_PAGE, array('state' => SOCIAL_STATE_PUBLISHED));

$childIds = [];

foreach ($childs as $child) {
    generateCombinations(0, 2, [$child->id], [], $child->id, $childIds);
    generateCombinations(0, 3, [$child->id], [], $child->id, $childIds);
    // Add more calls for additional combinations if needed
}
```

But to be completely honest the right way to solve this is to review your database structure.

Comment: Thank you very much Patrick. It works wonderfully well ! And if there are 4 values with 3 commas, how can I adapt your code ? I tried that, but it doesn't work.

for ($k = 1; $k <= 50; $k++)
{ if ($i != $k)
{ $childIds[] = "$child->id,$i,$j,$k";
$childIds[] = "$i,$child->id,$j,$k";
$childIds[] = "$i,$j,$child->id,$k";
$childIds[] = "$i,$j,$k,$child->id";
}
}

Comment: I changed the answer to support what you asked in the comment. It works but nested loops are CPU intensive. If you require this for a large amount of data, you need to change your database strategy.